# como fazer passagem por valor em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, referência

Tenho a seguint situação:

```
let a=[{nome:"oi"},{nome:"xau"}]
let b=Object.assign([], a)

b[0].nome=5

console.log(b) //[{nome:5},{nome:xau}]
console.log(a) //[{nome:5},{nome:xau}]
```

a pouco tempo atras perguntei aqui como passar valores sem ser por referencia, me falaram para usar o Object.assing, mas ainda assim nao esta dando certo, alguem pode me ajudar como faria para alterar o b[0].nome sem alterar o a?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar a mesma estrutura de `a`, no primeiro parâmetro de ´assign´?

Comment: tipo Object.assign([{}],a)? isso eu ja tentei e nao funcionou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método `assign` faz uma cópia rasa, ou seja, copia os valores de atributos que são do objeto, mas o que for referência ele copia o valor da referência. No seu exemplo `a` contém duas referências e por isso não está funcionando.

A sugestão que eu achei que poderia ajudar seria usar:

```
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução é serializar o objeto e deserializar em um novo usando `JSON`, assim:

```
let b=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
```

```js
let a=[{nome:"oi"},{nome:"xau"}]
let b=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))

b[0].nome=5

console.log(b[0]) //[{nome:5},{nome:xau}]
console.log(a[0]) //[{nome:5},{nome:xau}]
```

**EDIT**: @Everson apontou sobre explicar melhor a razão de serializar/deserializar:

O serializar transforma objeto em stream, no caso uma string JSON, o que irá "quebrar" a referência com o objeto original, e o deserializar transforma novamente em objeto, que a referência, criando um novo objeto

Comment: O serializar transforma objeto em stream, no caso uma string `JSON`, o que irá "quebrar" a referência com o objeto original, e o deserializar transforma novamente em objeto, que a referência, criando um novo objeto

Comment: Coloque na resposta, por gentileza.

Comment: Feito @Everson obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O que você precisa é fazer uma **Deep copy**.

Diferente da **Shallow copy** ou cópia rasa(explicada na resposta do [prmottajr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2833/prmottajr)), você precisa de uma cópia que seja criada sem qualquer referência aos dados originais, que seja aplicável para os arrays do objeto por exemplo.

Solução **criando um método:**

(método que criará um novo objeto e copiará as propriedades para esse objeto)

```js
var a=[{nome:"oi"},{nome:"xau"}]
var b = Clonar(a);

b[0].nome=5;

console.log(a, b);

function Clonar(source) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(source) === '[object Array]') {
        var clone = [];
        for (var i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
            clone[i] = Clonar(source[i]);
        }
        return clone;
    } else if (typeof(source)=="object") {
        var clone = {};
        for (var prop in source) {
            if (source.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                clone[prop] = Clonar(source[prop]);
            }
        }
        return clone;
    } else {
        return source;
    }
}
```

Solução com **Jquery**:

```js
var a=[{nome:"oi"},{nome:"xau"}]
var b = jQuery.extend(true, {}, a);

b[0].nome=5;
console.log(a, b);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Assim como já foi citado em outras respostas.
Solução **serializando e deserializando:**

```js
let a=[{nome:"oi"},{nome:"xau"}]
let b=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))

b[0].nome=5

console.log(a,b)
```

**Fontes**:

- [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in
  JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)
- [JavaScript: How to pass object by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574054/javascript-how-to-pass-object-by-value?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)