# Javascript, falha em "salvar" a ordenação de arrays

Tags: javascript, array

## Falha em "salvar" a ordenação de arrays

Eu montei um código para ordenar um array e armazenar a os seus valores em um segundo array, porém, quando eu o ordeno novamente ele modifica o valor atribuído ao segundo array e ao invés de aparecer:

```
Ordenamento Alfabético: 

Chave 0 Valor 1
Chave 1 Valor 10
Chave 2 Valor 2
Chave 3 Valor 200
Chave 4 Valor 3

Ordenamento Numérico: 

Chave 0 Valor 1
Chave 1 Valor 2
Chave 2 Valor 3
Chave 3 Valor 10
Chave 4 Valor 200
```

Aparece:

```
Ordenamento Alfabético: 

Chave 0 Valor 1
Chave 1 Valor 2
Chave 2 Valor 3
Chave 3 Valor 10
Chave 4 Valor 200

Ordenamento Numérico: 

Chave 0 Valor 1
Chave 1 Valor 2
Chave 2 Valor 3
Chave 3 Valor 10
Chave 4 Valor 200
```

Alguém pode me ajudar e dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

```js
// Variáveis
var matriz = [];
var novamatriz = [];
var i = 0;

// Principal
matriz = [1, 2, 10, 3, 200];

matriz.sort();

novamatriz[0] = matriz;

matriz.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a - b);
});

novamatriz[1] = matriz;

// Console
console.log("Ordenamento Alfabético: \n\n");

for (i = 0; i < novamatriz[0].length; i++) {
  console.log("Chave " + i + " Valor " + novamatriz[0][i]);
}

console.log("\nOrdenamento Numérico: \n\n");

for (i = 0; i < novamatriz[1].length; i++) {
  console.log("Chave " + i + " Valor " + novamatriz[0][i]);
}
```

Comment: quando você copia um objeto igualando, assim `novamatriz[0] = matriz;` você tem duas variáveis apontando para o mesmo objeto, ou seja, se alterar **novamatriz** ou **matriz** estará alterando a mesma coisa. Sugiro ler essa resposta, em especial a diferença em *valor e referência*: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15260/57220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz umas alterações comentadas no seu código:

```js
var matriz = [];
var novamatriz = [];
var i = 0;

// Principal
matriz = [1, 2, 10, 3, 200];

matriz.sort();

/* aqui estou fazendo uma copia realmente do objeto
   para isso, serializo e depois deserializo, criando algo novo */
novamatriz[0] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matriz));

matriz.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a - b);
});

/* aqui mesmo processo */
novamatriz[1] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matriz)) ;

// Console
console.log("Ordenamento Alfabético: \n\n");

for (i = 0; i < novamatriz[0].length; i++) {
  console.log("Chave " + i + " Valor " + novamatriz[0][i]);
}

console.log("\nOrdenamento Numérico: \n\n");

for (i = 0; i < novamatriz[1].length; i++) {
  // nessa linha no seu código estava pegando novamatriz[0] que estava errado
  console.log("Chave " + i + " Valor " + novamatriz[1][i]);
}
```

Em resumo, usei a combinação de `JSON.stringify` e `JSON.parse` para criar um novo objeto, e não uma referência para o mesmo objeto.

Aqui uma resposta comentando o mesmo problema: [como-fazer-passagem-por-valor-em-javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286125/como-fazer-passagem-por-valor-em-javascript/286129#286129)

E aqui outra boa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15260/57220